# Firefox addon to block attempts to make text unselectable?

Tags: firefox

Is there a firefox addon that will block attempts to prevent the user from selecting text? Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean all kinds of attempts that could try to prevent this (e.g., with CSS or JavaScript), or does `noselect` refer to a specific technology?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I assumed CSS was the only way. Something that successfully kills it on a substantial number of webpages would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/righttoclick/

Stops javascript annoyances such as forbidden right click, forbidden text selection or disabled features like copy/save images from web-pages.

for new firefox (quantum)

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/absolute-enable-right-click/

Get The Best Browsing Experience Without Limitations And Restrictions In An Online World

- Remove Copy Text Protection On All Website
- Force Enable Right Click Button
- Allow Copy And Highlight
- Disable Annoying Dialog Message (Not Able To Copy Content On This Webpage)
- Re-Enable Context Menu
- Include "Absolute Mode" To Force Remove Any Type Of Protection

Comment: This works on the offending website that led me here, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[NoScript (NS)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/)

Most site protection (noselect, norightclick and whatnot) usually use JavaScript (JS). NS by default blocks every JS not whitelisted by default (easily configurable whitelisting). Not allowing an entire site and connected resources to use additional scripts may make the page look basic.

Comment: This would probably work but mucks up modern websites... I went for the other solution.